# Make webview work on different webpages

Tags: java, android

What I need to change in code for buttons and code for `webview` to make `webview` work for multiple buttons with different web pages.

Here's java code for button:

```
Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.klase101);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MatematikaTem10.this, WebViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);      
        }                     
    });
```

Java code for `webview`:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.uzdevumi.lv/p/matematika/10-klase/vektori-986");

        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the url as parameter to the `WebViewActivity` and use the url to load `WebView`

Do this on button click

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MatematikaTem10.this, WebViewActivity.class); // change context if required
intent.putExtra("url", url); // url you want to open in WebView
startActivity(intent);
```

In `WebViewActivity` do this

```
myWebView.loadUrl(getIntent().getStringExtra("url"));
```